# Effect of continuous interaction on pairwise contrasts

Tags: r, regression, interaction, lm, lsmeans

I have a 3-level categorical variable `type` interacting with a continuous variable `duration` (centered) in a linear model. The categorical variable is sum-coded, so there are 2 parameters in the model for that variable, which don't correspond directly to the levels of the factor.

I'm using `lsmeans::lsmeans` to test the contrasts between different levels of `type`. The hypothesis is that, as `duration` increases, the difference between the first two levels of `type` should grow larger. In particular, as `duration` increases, I expect the second level to have a larger effect on the response variable while the first level should not be sensitive to `duration`.

So this is what I'm doing now:

```
mod = lm(response ~ type * duration, data=data)
lsmeans(mod, pairwise ~ type)
```

How do I test whether the contrast between the first two levels of `item` changes as a function of the continuous variable?

Comment: This is the answer I found: use `lst = lsmeans::lstrends(mod, ~type, var="duration")` then `cld(lst)` or `pairs(lst)`

Comment: The `lstrends` approach you show compares the slopes of the duration trends for each treatment. So it relates to your question but doesn't answer it directly. How about if you do `lsm = lsmeans(mod, ~ type|duration, at = list(duration = c(...))` where you supply a few typical duration values. Then `print(lsm)` and `pairs(lsm)`, the latter showing how the conditions compare at each duration in the at list.